# How to extend ReactJS' Link component and show innerHtml

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I looked at many sources on how to extend a React component by inheritance. The examples I found were always adding events and not manipulating the `innerHtml`. So, I could not find a simpler way to do this:

```
// React packages
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class LinkX extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Link
                className={this.props.className}
                to={this.props.to}
                replace={this.props.replace}
            >
                <span>{this.props.html}</span> // Wrap with span
            </Link>
    }
}
```

In my example, I want to add a `<span>` that surrounds the inner text of the link. So, I added a new property `html` that I put as the text of the `Link` instance.

Then, I use it this way:

```
<LinkX to={"/"} html="Home" />
```

I wonder if there is a way to get the innerHtml from the LinkX component, surround it with `<span>`, and put that inside the Link without using `props`. Then use it like this:

```
<LinkX to={"/"}>Home</LinkX>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like you need to use [children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) like this:

```
export default class LinkX extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Link
                className={this.props.className}
                to={this.props.to}
                replace={this.props.replace}
            >
                <span>{this.props.children}</span> // Wrap with span
            </Link>
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this
`<LinkX><b>bold</b></LinkX>`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Is there a way to extend Link instead of React.Component and achieve the same?

Comment: Not actually, @bluetoft! I need to add the <span> without having it in the innerHTML of the LinkX component.